# Mono: Apache mod_mono installing issue on Ubuntu

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I am trying to install mod_mono on Ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. I have tried following command and got error:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono mono-apache-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-mono : Depends: mono-apache-server (< 3.8.1) but 4.2-2~xamarin1 is to be installed or
                                mono-apache-server4 (< 3.8.1) but 4.2-2~xamarin1 is to be installed or
                                mono-apache-server2 (< 3.8.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have installed latest mono version.

```
 sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Please suggest me what should I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Install `mono-apache-server4` instead of `mono-apache-server` with `libapache2-mod-mono`

So, try:

`apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono mono-apache-server4`